# Why does this function call throws "await is only valid in async function" Syntax Error even though the function is async?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

There is a loadJson function that returns the Json of a firebase link

```js
async function loadJson(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    return data
}
```

I am trying to assign the value of `loadJson()` to this variable and use it in a promise.

```js
let indexJSON = await loadJson(url)

indexJSON.then(() => {      
    // some code
})
```

But why does this code throws the following error?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await | "await won’t work in the top-level code". Your loadJson() return async function so you do not have to await for it, when will be ready will return your data value. Try doing loadJson(url).then(()=>{}) or let indexJSON = loadJson(url), will have to work. Await can only live inside async funcion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is your `await` here:

```
let indexJSON = await loadJson(url)

indexJSON.then(() => {      
    // some code
})
```

if you want the promise call the function without `await`:

```
let indexJSON = loadJson(url)
indexJSON.then(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and make use of async-await, otherwise use `then` to evaluate the promise.

```
(async () => {
  let indexJSON = await loadJson(url)
  console.log(indexJSON);
})()
```

Comment: He seems to want to use the promise in the line below. So if he wants the promise he can just remove the `await`

Comment: This is a nice alternative though. Especially if you want to use try and catch and finally